# Shorten BibLaTeX output

Tags: biblatex, biber

The following MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{filecontents}    
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=none,citestyle=numeric-comp,giveninits=true,doi=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Refs.bib}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{number}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\begin{filecontents}{Refs.bib}

@article{reuter2002renormalization,
  title={Renormalization group flow of quantum gravity in the Einstein-Hilbert truncation},
  author={Reuter, M and Saueressig, Frank},
  journal={Physical Review D},
  volume={65},
  number={6},
  pages={065016},
  year={2002},
  publisher={APS},
  doi={10.1103/PhysRevD.65.065016},
  archivePrefix={arXiv},
  eprint={hep-th/0110054}
}

\end{filecontents}

\end{document}
```

prints

> M Reuter and Frank Saueressig. “Renormalization group flow of quantum
>   gravity in the Einstein-Hilbert truncation”. In: Physical Review D 65.6
>   (2002), p. 065016. doi:10.1103/PhysRevD.65.065016.
>   arXiv:hep-th/0110054.1

This is much too long. I would like to remove

> M Reuter and F<strike>rank</strike> Saueressig. “Renormalization group flow of quantum
>   gravity in the Einstein-Hilbert truncation”. <strike>In:</strike> Physical Review D 65<strike>.6</strike>
>   (2002), <strike>p.</strike> 065016. <strike>doi:10.1103/PhysRevD.65.065016.
>   arXiv:</strike> hep-th/0110054.1

resulting in (note the bold volume number)

> M. Reute, F. Saueressig. “Renormalization group flow of quantum
>   gravity in the Einstein-Hilbert truncation”. Phys. Rev. **D 65** (2002),
>   065016. hep-th/0110054.

Adding the options `giveninits=true`, `doi=false` and the commands `\renewbibmacro{in:}{}`, `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{number}}` gives

> M. Reuter and F. Saueressig. “Renormalization group flow of quantum
>   gravity inthe Einstein-Hilbert truncation”. Physical Review D 65 (2002),
>   p. 065016. arXiv:hep-th/0110054.

Better but not there yet. Can someone help me

- remove the "and" before last authors,
- abbreviate the journal name,
- print bold volume numbers,
- remove "p." or "pp." in front of page numbers or ranges,
- remove "arXiv" in front of eprint number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{filecontents}    
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=none,citestyle=numeric-comp,giveninits=true,doi=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Refs.bib}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{number}}

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\newcommand\prd{Phys.~Rev.~D}

\makeatletter
\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:arxiv}{%
%  arXiv\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{http://arxiv.org/\abx@arxivpath/#1}{%
       \nolinkurl{#1}%
       \iffieldundef{eprintclass}
         {}
         {\addspace\texttt{\mkbibbrackets{\thefield{eprintclass}}}}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}
     \iffieldundef{eprintclass}
       {}
       {\addspace\texttt{\mkbibbrackets{\thefield{eprintclass}}}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Reference: \cite{reuter2002renormalization}

\printbibliography

\begin{filecontents}{Refs.bib}

@article{reuter2002renormalization,
  title={Renormalization group flow of quantum gravity in the Einstein-Hilbert truncation},
  author={Reuter, M and Saueressig, Frank},
  journal={\prd},
  volume={65},
  number={6},
  pages={065016},
  year={2002},
  publisher={APS},
  doi={10.1103/PhysRevD.65.065016},
  archivePrefix={arXiv},
  eprint={hep-th/0110054}
}

\end{filecontents}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Didn't think removing "arXiv" would be so elaborate. Using this in my main document, I get an "Undefined control sequence" for `\abx` which disappears if I remove the `hyperref` package. Is there any reason I can't simply replace `\abx@arxivpath` with `abs`, as in "https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0110054"?

Comment: Also, could you briefly explain why the case distinctions in `\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:arxiv}{...` are necessary?

Comment: @Casimir I simply copied the `\DeclareFieldFormat`... from `biblatex.def` and commented out the line with the hardcoded arxiv name. The case distinction should deal with hyperref package beeing loaded and not beeing loaded.

Comment: @Casimir `\abx@arxivpath` is defined as `\newcommand*{\abx@arxivpath}{abs}` so the result should be the same. Maybe try to wrap it in `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` if you use it with hyperref, see my edited answer

Comment: I see. So if I _do_ use `hyperref` and don't care about `eprintclass` or special typesetting, `\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:arxiv}{\href{http://arxiv.org/abs/#1}{#1}}` works just as well?

Comment: @Casimir Do so on your own risk :)